# Using hex linguist package in Phoenix Framework

Tags: internationalization, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I use the linguist package with Phoenix? I'm trying to have internationalization in a web page. I have added the package to mix.exs and ran `mix deps.get` with success.

Now, I don't know where in which folder to write the module file of the package as well as if it should be ex or exs in extension like the other country language file in the Usage case (fr.exs).

Also, after writing the module, how exactly would I apply it to my HTML tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quickly looking at the readme it seems you specify the path to the local file in the `locale` declaration when writing your `I18n` module. It's this line:

```
locale "fr", Path.join([__DIR__, "fr.exs"])
```

In this case it says "look into the current directory for a file named 'fr.exs'", but you can specify whatever you want, for example something like this:

```
locale "fr", Path.join(["lib", "translations", "fr.exs"])
```

Then in your views you just call the functions on the `I18n` module you defined, like the readme says:

```
<%=  I18n.t!("fr", "greeting") %>
```

Comment: But where do I define the module itself (the following code)?


`defmodule I18n do
  use Linguist.Vocabulary

  locale "en", [
    flash: [
      notice: [
        hello: "hello %{first} %{last}",
        bye: "bye now, %{name}!"
      ]
    ],
    users: [
      title: "Users",
      profiles: [
        title: "Profiles",
      ]
    ]
  ]

  locale "fr", Path.join([__DIR__, "fr.exs"])

end`

Comment: You can add it to web/i18n.ex in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the sample code [at the Linguist GitHub Page](https://github.com/chrismccord/linguist)?  You may also want to look at the [phoenix_linguist](https://github.com/jxs/phoenix_linguist) github page as well.

Comment: That is exactly my doubt. I'm trying to apply the sample code from their github page, but I don't know where I'm supposed to write the first part of the code and what extension to use.
I'll look into Phoenix's package too, thanks

Comment: Every project can benefit from learning about the problems that newcomers are facing. If you want be a great person and help those coming after you, improve the Readme after you managed to get it working, and then make a PR on Github ;-)

Comment: The phoenix_linguist package instructions have me stumped as well. My project stops working once I type that Plug (the syntax is most likely wrong from what I can perceive).
Also just noticed that it hasn't  been updated in 4 months and the sole existing issue is yet to be answered.